# Selection not centered on selected object

Tags: modeling

I have a really strange thing happening right now - I'm sure there's a reason for it, and it's almost certainly something I did when creating the model, but I really want to figure out a way to fix it..

[image: off-center selection]

I have this window I'm modelling for an architecture-style render I'm planning. The object is just the window, and everything else is behaving properly, but for this particular object, the selection/center point is way off to one side, and I don't know why.

What is going on, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you moved the geometry while in Edit mode, leaving the origin behind. Use the Origin option in the toolshelf (<kbd>T</kbd>) and ‘set origin to geometry’ to move it automatically back to the geometry.